# Как реализовать выборку методом «бутстрэп»?

Tags: python, статистика

Существует непараметрический метод для работы с выборками очень небольшого размера — [Бутстрэп](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%83%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8D%D0%BF_(%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)). Как может выглядеть его базовая реализация?

Comment: Выборку чего, куда? Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: вы не спрашивали, а типо обменялись знаниями? эм....

Comment: @Kromster Это вопрос из статистики. Его аналогом в мире программирования будет что–то вроде «как реализовать хранение пар данных ключ-значение». В этом контексте выражение «*Выборку чего, куда?*»  звучит для меня как «*какой словарь, русского языка что–ли?*». То есть оно не выглядит состоятельным. Это стандартная терминология. Поясните, что именно вы бы хотели видеть в вопросе?

Comment: @michael_best Примерно так и есть. Участник [спросил про это в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48128428#48128428), я решил ответить на сайте, чтобы не потерялось.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky затрудняюсь вам ответить, т.к. сам не в теме, но .. «как реализовать хранение пар данных ключ-значение» это чрезвычайно широкий вопрос на который нельзя дать однозначный ответ. Хранение где, на диске, на сервере, в облаке, в редиске, в кэше, в памяти? Какие данные, какие ключи, какие объемы, требования по скорости или надежности или еще как-то .. этого всего "вопрос" не содержит. Не мне вам рассказывать, что такое хороший вопрос, как-бы ..

Comment: @Kromster аналогия не очень подходящая. Вопрос больше похож на `Как можно реализовать Qucik-sort на Питоне?` – здесь уточнять нечего :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Идея применения бутсрэпа в том, что у нас есть выборка небольшого размера и нам надо оценить, например, среднее. Вместо подсчета среднего самой этой выборки, мы извлекаем `n_samples` выборок *с возвращением* (то есть элементы могут повторяться) из исходной. У полученных выборок считаем среднее. Его уже оцениваем, вместо оценки среднего исходной выборки.

Реализация с помощью numpy:

```
def get_bootstrap_samples(data, n_samples):
    indices = np.random.randint(0, len(data), (n_samples, len(data)))
    samples = data[indices]
    return samples
```

Вызов:

```
n_samples = 1000
a_samples = get_bootstrap_samples(a_data, n_samples)
b_samples = get_bootstrap_samples(b_data, n_samples)
```

Массивы `a_samples` и `b_samples` имеют размер `(n_samples, len(data))`.  Далее мы можем посмотреть на необходимый параметр. Например, среднее:

```
deltas = map(lambda x: x[1].mean() - x[0].mean(), zip(a_samples, b_samples))
```

И посчитать интервал для получаемого значения:

```
def stat_intervals(stat, alpha):
    boundaries = np.percentile(stat, [100 * alpha / 2., 100 * (1 - alpha / 2.)])
    return boundaries

intervals = stat_intervals(deltas, 0.05)
```

Comment: а где пояснения что тут происходит? :)

Comment: @Grundy Спасибо за указание на недочет. Добавил!

Comment: Есть какие-то рекомендации/ограничения по соотношению _небольшого размера выборки_ и `n_samples`?

Comment: @mkkik К сожалению, я не могу точно ответить на ваш вопрос, так как использовал этот подход только в учебных целях. Если вы в курсе, пожалуйста, дайте ссылку! Я обязательно изучу и дополню ответ.